# Rendering javascript in template on initial page load meteorjs

Tags: google-api, meteor

I'm trying to load a chart from the google charts api.  For the most part it is working as planned.  The issue comes on the initial page load.  If I navigate from another part of my site to the page (using router) it loads fine.  However, if I hit the refresh button on the page the chart does not load until I leave and re-enter the page.

I have this in my main.html header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

and in my template.templatename.rendered AND template.templatename.created I have

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {'callback':function() {},packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
Deps.autorun(function () { 
             drawChart()
             })
```

Where drawChart() calls the google visualization commands.  I do understand I'm probably calling some repetitive code currently, but all of this is in an effort to get the page to load when I hit refresh.

I appreciate any help.

Please let me know if there is any more info needed.  Thanks.

Comment: Why dont u use template renderd function?

Comment: And router should have after callbacks that you can put your drawChart() In there

Answer (score 1):

Placing the ***Google jsapi*** file in the ***main.html*** header will cause the browser to run the ***Javascript*** after the ***DOM*** is completely loaded, which is too late for your purposes.

***Meteor*** is calling your `google.load` code before the ***DOM*** is completely rendered, so when you hit refresh page, the ***jsapi*** file is undefined when ***Meteor*** calls `google.load`.

However, if you navigate away and then back, the ***DOM*** has already been loaded once, so the chart will be rendered correctly.

To solve this, I would suggest just saving a local version of `http://www.google.com/jsapi` in your client folder.

Thus, Meteor will load it before it calls the `google.load` code.